# how to support multiple languages on Alpine Linux 3.6.0?

Tags: localization, alpine-linux

I am using Alpine Linux 3.6.0 as my base OS in a docker container and running a Spring Boot project.

When I do one of the following in my terminal:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:10000/sco/scorpius -H 'accept-language: ja-JP'
curl -X GET http://localhost:10000/sco/scorpius -H 'accept-language: zh-CN'
```

I get something like this as my HTTP response:

```
{"message":"å ´åã«ãã£ã¦ã¯ãä¸é¨ããã¹ã}
```

when it should be:

```
{"message":"時に何かがすべて"}
```

How do I add the japanese, chinese, etc. language packages for Alpine? I can not seem to find any here: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages